# Iterate over an array, do a query to mongodb against some of its data

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous

A common situation. I have a collection, `comments` which has a field called `userid` and another `postid`, but there's nothing embedded, just references. So, given a postid I get the comments querying comments collection, but now, I also want to get some info stored in the user collection. So, given an array of comments,I want to do something like this:

```
for(var j = 0; j < comments.length; j++) {

    users.byUsername(comments[j].username, function(err, data){
        comments[j].user = data;
    });
}
```

But I get that comments is `undefined`, how can I solve this?

Comment: Where does the `comments` collection come from?

Comment: from a mongodb query in a different layer I cannot access

Comment: Then how can you be sure it has a value?

Comment: Can we just assume there are values there?